# How can I paramaterize my selenium tests to run through multiple scenarios using saucelabs

Tags: selenium, testing, junit, automated-tests, saucelabs

I have a selenium automation framework which uses junit to run tests locally on a browser of my choice. I currently use junitparams to parameterize some of my tests. e.g

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class loginPage extends BaseTestClass{
   @Test
   @FileParameters(value = "src/test/resources/Test data/login.csv", mapper = CsvWithHeaderMapper.class)
   public void login(String username, String pwd) throws Exception{
   }
}
```

There are tests I have for logging into a website and I use junitparams with a csv file to run through multiple different login scenarios. I am now looking to start using saucelabs to run my tests across multiple different browser/os combinations simultaneously. My question is how do I achieve both the saucelabs parallel tests and parametrized tests at the same time? I have seen examples for saucelabs like the following:
https://github.com/saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks/Java-Junit-Selenium

But the issue I will run into is that I cannot use multiple different runners. I need to use a single runner as the Junit @RunWith annotatation requires. Is there an easy way to combine both the ConcurrentParameterized.class runner used in the saucelabs example and the JUnitParamsRunner.class I am currently utilising for local execution?

EDIT:
I found the following that confirms I cannot use 2 separate runners and appears to suggest merging two runners would be very difficult. Instead I'm guessing I will have to change the way sauce labs integration is handled. https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams-spring-integration-example

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [SauceryJ](https://github.com/Sauceforge/SauceryJ).  It integrates Jenkins, the Sauce OnDemand plugin, and your testing code with SauceLabs.

Example class [here](https://github.com/Sauceforge/SauceryJ/blob/master/test/src/test/java/au/com/fullcirclesolutions/saucery/tests/GuineaPigTest.java).

Full disclosure:  I wrote and maintain SauceryJ